# Tax Refund with D visa (Italy): possible?

Tags: italy, refunds, long-stay-visas, taxes, tax-refunds

I am studying at a university in Italy with a D-type visa. Also, a few days ago, I received my Permesso di Soggiorno card, valid for 1 year.

My question is, I will return to my country in May (non-EU country). Can I get a tax refund on the electronic items I purchased?

Kind regards,

Comment: I assume with tax refund you mean VAT? [Guide to VAT refund for visitors to the EU - European Commission](https://taxation-customs.ec.europa.eu/guide-vat-refund-visitors-eu_en)

Comment: @MarkJohnson Yes sir

Answer (score 4):

Tax refund is for non-residents (tourists and other visitors, nationals living abroad). You are a resident, and thus not eligible. Whether Customs will go through your passport and verify that you are not a resident depends on each officer's mood, and how busy the counter is. But legally, that's a no.